# External Service - Parsing XML/JSON

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, xml, parser, external-services

I am trying to implement an integration with a third-party system to Insert Products into Salesforce. I have created the External Service, consumed the schema, and was also able to make a call to the web service through Flow Action and get the return(200) by debugging the flow.

The issue I have is that the return is either in JSON or XML format with multiple Products. Do Salesforce flows have the capability to get the XML/JSON data, somehow parse it, and Insert it into the Product2 object? Or do I need to implement Apex XML parser and get rid of the flow altogether?

I would like a point-and-click solution but I am not sure if flows can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can directly consume the contents of the service. This [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_external_services_example_create_flow.htm&type=5) article tells you exactly how to do it. In summary, though, you create a Apex-Defined Variable using the External Service as the data type, then use an Assignment operation to create the records in the flow, and finally commit those changes using a Create Records or Update Records element. You should be able to do this completely without a single line of code, which is one of the primary benefits of using External Services.